# how do you extract first word after specific word in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get social media usernames from a post. This is my code so far.

```
social_media=['kik']
df['socials'] = df['Request'].str.extract('({})'.format('|'.join(social_media)), 
                    flags=re.IGNORECASE, expand=False).str.lower().fillna('')

print(df['socials'])
```

This code prints `kik` for the rows that have a `kik` listed

How can I get it to output the username that's listed after `kik`

This is a sample of my dataframe:

```
Request
-------
0 my kik abcd
1 ig bby
2 check out my kik:1234
3 Kik hehehaha
```

My code outputs this:

```
socials
-------
0 kik
1
2 kik
3 kik
```

I'd like it to output this:

```
socials
-------
0 abcd
1
2 1234
3 hehehaha
```

Comment: Can you provide a small example of what the DataFrame currently contains, what you've tried, and what you expect the output to look like?

Comment: @Simon just posted an example!

Comment: "...get it to output the username that's listed after 'kik'" is not clear. What is the rule for identifying a user name? Should we disregard any colons or spaces following 'kik'? Skip commas? Slashes? Is the username always a sequence of letters or digits, as in your examples? Is it always one word? Be precise!

Comment: @CarySwoveland The username is always a sequence of letters and/or digits and always one word.  Sometimes there's a colon or an addition space after kik

Comment: That's helpful, but I was asking what could appear between `'kik'` and the username. For example, if the string were `'kik: __ 1234'` would we conclude `1234` is the username? What if it were `'kik: 1234A 22 B'`? Let me give you an example of a statement that provides the rule for identifying the username: "the username is the first string of digits or letters following `'kik'` that is preceded by a space and is either followed by a space or is at the end of the string." I have no idea if that's actually want you want, but that's the type of precise statement you need.

Comment: When asked for clarification it's always best to edit your question rather than try to elaborate in comments. Question should be stand-alone, in part because not all readers read all comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create sample data

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['request'] = ['my kik abcd', 'ig bby', 'check out my kik:1234', 'Kik hehehaha']
```

Filter data looking for only those that contain 'kik', case insensitive

```
filtered_df = df[df['request'].str.contains('kik', flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
```

Look through rows that have 'kik' and get everything after it:

```
df.loc[filtered_df.index, 'test'] = [re.split('kik', row, flags=re.IGNORECASE, maxsplit=1)[-1] for row in filtered_df['request']]
```

A few things to note

- The 2nd row value still contains the semicolon, you can simply do a `str.replace` to get rid of it
- I limit the split to a maximum of once (`maxsplit=1`), therefore it will always take everything after kik `[-1]`.

Meaning a string of `'kik junk junk junk'` will result in `'junk junk junk'`

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help and answer my question! I really appreciate it!